# In "Good As Gold" How did the Doctor "destroy" the angel?

Tags: doctor-who, weeping-angels

In the Doctor Who Script To Screen Episode [Good as Gold](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_TfU8bTpqo) the Doctor seemed to have "destroyed" the Weeping Angel.

How did he do that?

He has never been shown to be able to do that before!

Comment: You're The Doctor. Shouldn't you know?

Comment: @Xantec o ha ha :-P

Comment: Hmm, other question: From "Fear Her" we know that the Doctor actually carried the torch into the stadium himself. Should we not have seen the tenth Doctor come into the Tardis?

Comment: *Bigger* question; how does a Weeping Angel chase someone through a stadium full of people? :)

Comment: (For those who may not have seen it yet, please note that "Good as Gold" was written by schoolchildren and, if Doctor Who had such a thing as "canon" this would clearly be not be part of it...)

Comment: @Xantec He hasn't done it yet, so he doesn't know and wants to know how it is done so he can do it in the future.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield That explains why it wasn't the Doctor carrying the torch, since we've already seen him light the flame at the 2012 Olympics in the episode *Fear Her*.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple, really. He used his sonic screwdriver to lock onto the signature energy of the Olympic flame. Using that, he fiddled with it until it created an effect that caused the Weeping Angel to be, to put it simply, ignited by the very energy it was trying to feed off of.

Answer (score 2):

We know that the Weeping Angels feed off energy - time energy, by sending people back in time, and also real energy, leeching it from the Byzantium.  The Doctor comments on its attempt to steal the Flame in *Good as Gold*,

> It's trying to steal the Olympic Flame [and] spoil the very spirit of respect, excellence and friendship it represents.

I think it was trying to leech off that energy, and what the Doctor did was set up a feedback loop back into the Flame (as seen by the Flame increasing in size prior to the Angel's "demise") which the Angel leeched too much energy off - causing it to lose control of its defence mechanism (its statue body) and that exploded.

However once the Flame was removed and the power levels were back to normal, the Angel reformed as it was now able to exert control over its abilities and defence mechanism once more.

Answer (score 1):

It seemed like he just broke the statue, not kill the Weeping Angel.  Don't forget the the Angels turn into stone.  Stone can be destroyed.

Comment: Um they don't magically become stone as in actual stone. If they did they would be no danger whatsoever as you could simply smash 'em. They are quantum locked, which means they freeze. When people say they "turn to stone" that's an analogy.